# Use Aweber API to create a list from the website

Tags: api, email, aweber

After spending a lot of time into the Aweber documentation, i coudn't find if i can create a subscribers list from the API. Is this possible, and if it is, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but the API docs leave a whole lot to be desired -- like Operating Thetan Level and can read minds. From what I can tell you have to take some credentials you get with your list, authenticate some kind of oAuth mechanism that isn't easy, and then on the respond from that you get all the necessary IDs you can use to add a subscriber into a list. You'll want to connect with http://labs.aweber.com/ to learn more. I'm still waiting on my callback from AWeber Support so that I can grasp this all, myself.

Answer (score 0):

i have also spend many hours to find it, but at last, i have used this - 
**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686007/aweber-automatic-subscription**